# Error when importing the tqdm module in Python

Tags: python, tqdm

I have a script that imports the Python `tqdm` module.

I can import the `tqdm` module from a Jupyter notebook, for instance, but not when running the script from the command line.

When running the script from the command line, I see the following error message:

```
File "RetreiveData.py", line 19, in <module> from tqdm import tqdm
    ImportError: No module named tqdm
```

My script is called from a command line as follows:

```
python RetrieveData.py <arg1> <arg2>
```

My environment variables are:

**PATH:**

```
C:\Users<joesmith\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2;C:\Users\joesmith\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Users\joesmith\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Library\bin; C:\Company\Libs\python-2.7\Windows_x86
```

**PYTHON PATH:**

```
C:\Users\joesmith\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2;C:\Users\joesmith\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Scripts;C:\Users\joesmith\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\Library\bin; C:\Company\Libs\python-2.7\Windows_x86
```

Does anyone see why this error is occurring?

Thanks!

Comment: you have install `tqdm` on default python and possibly jupyter uses different python version

Comment: When I launch Python from the console, I'm able to import tqdm.  How would I see if Jupyter is using a different version of Python?

Comment: `import platform; print(platform.python_version())` run this on jupyter and on python intepreter through console and check the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Anaconda this worked for me:

```
sudo <anaconda path>/bin/python3.6 -m pip install tqdm
```

(after your working env is activated)

On my linux machine I substituted `<anaconda path>` with:

```
anaconda3
```

In your machine try with `Anaconda2` once inside your working env for your machine like so:

```
sudo Anaconda2/Library/bin/python-2.7 -m pip install tqdm
```

Make sure you have pip installed.